# Geolocation html5 not working for Oppo and Honor Android phones

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, geolocation

This is code I am using to build Google Maps this is working in 80% of Android phones but the local phone manufacturer is not supporting this as I am not able to get coordinates in phones like OPPO, HONOR many more.

I tried Google Geolocation API that doesn't give exact latlng.

```js
function inti () {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geoLocationSucess);



            backview = "views/home.html";
        }

   
}



function writeAddress(latLng) {

    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode({
        "location": latLng
    },
        function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

                var rr = results[0].formatted_address;

                var res = rr.split(",");
                //  alert(res[0] + ", " +res[1]+ "," + res[2]);


            } else
                "Unable to retrieve your address" + "<br />";
        });
}


function initialize() {

    //checker to watch position every sec if position fixed it will not refresh
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geoLocationSucess, showError);

    } else
        alert("Your Device does't support geolocation.");
}

function geoLocationSucess(position) {

    var userLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);

    writeAddress(userLatLng)

    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 15,
        center: userLatLng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var mapObject = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), myOptions);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: mapObject,
        position: userLatLng

    });
    var sunCircle = {
        strokeColor: "#7DB1E8",
        strokeOpacity: 0.5,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        fillColor: "#7DB1E8",
        fillOpacity: 0.25,
        map: mapObject,
        center: userLatLng,
        radius: 200 // in meters
    };
    var cityCircle = new google.maps.Circle(sunCircle);
    cityCircle.bindTo(center, marker);




}
function showError(error) {

    switch (error.code) {
        case 1:
            alert("User denied the request for Geolocation.");
            break;
        case 2:
            alert("Location information is unavailable. Please ensure Location is On");
            break;
        case 3:
            break;
        case 4:
            alert("An unknown error occurred.");
            break;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <style>
        #googleMap {
            width: 100%;
            height: 80vh;
        }
    </style>
  <body>
    <div id="googleMap"> </div> <span id="locate" data-role="touch"><a data-role="button"  onclick="initialize()"
        id="locate" style=" width:50%;background:#18515C;" >Locate Me
    </a></span> <span id="punch" data-role="touch"><a data-role="button"  onclick="punch()"
        id="punch" style="width:40%;background:#18515C; ">Punch
    </a></span>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Are u using geolocation plugin cordova or html5 geolocation api ??

Comment: i am using html5 geolocation api

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<p><button onclick="geoFindMe()">Show my location</button></p>
<div id="out"></div>
```

script

```
function geoFindMe() {
  var output = document.getElementById("out");

  if (!navigator.geolocation){
    output.innerHTML = "<p>Geolocation is not supported by your browser</p>";
    return;
  }

  function success(position) {
    var latitude  = position.coords.latitude;
    var longitude = position.coords.longitude;

    output.innerHTML = '<p>Latitude is ' + latitude + '° <br>Longitude is ' + longitude + '°</p>';

    var img = new Image();
    img.src = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=" + latitude + "," + longitude + "&zoom=13&size=300x300&sensor=false";

    output.appendChild(img);
  }

  function error() {
    output.innerHTML = "Unable to retrieve your location";
  }

  output.innerHTML = "<p>Locating…</p>";

  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
}
```

If this doesn't work use the cordova geolocation plugin and try.

Try with geolocation options.

The result will be affected by the following reasons,

- Mobile webkit version
- Internet speed of the mobile
- The device has a clear and uninterrupted view of the sky. GPS’s listen for a very weak signal from multiple satellites. These signals can be partially or completely blocked by buildings, thick foliage, vehicle roofs, etc.

Comment: I have tried each and every things to get location in oppo and honor phones of html5 geolocation api it is not coming for these phones

Comment: can u catch me on naresh.k.suruvu@gmail.com

Comment: i don't have access to operate gmail